# Exim on VPS receives emails meant for MX

Tags: email, vps, dovecot, exim, microsoft-office-365

Last weekend I transitioned a company website and corporate tools from an old server to a VPS which was set up beforehand on test.example.com and then moved to example.net. While the box does send some automated messages it is not our mail exchange server. The mail exchange server in DNS is still set to our custom microsoftonline url, this URL didn't change.

Going through the error logs I see that *some* emails, to legitimate users, are being rejected by the VPS. 99% of the emails sent go through microsoftonline's services and are delivered to the recipient. In fact one email from a colleague in China was delivered correctly through Microsoft and the next email from the same person was rejected by the web-server.

My problem is not that the server rejects emails - I don't want to relay external emails, my problem is that it catches these emails at all.

Any Input is appreciated! I am no exim, dns, or webhost master.

Comment: In the absence of an MX record the sending host will query for an A record for the domain and send email there. I suspect there's a problem with locating your MX record. I'd start by looking at the DNS zone for the domain in question.

Answer (score 1):

DNS data is cached.  If you didn't reduce the TTL before the move, then entries can be cached until they time out.

If you can configure your old server to defer rather than reject email arriving from the Internet, the messages should eventually be delivered to the correct server.  Alternatively, and likely more appropriately configure the Exim server to listen only on localhost.  Legitimate servers will retry for a few days before bouncing the email.  That should be sufficient time for them to find the correct MX record.